# Regex match from response using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to get the view-source of a website and then doing a regex match. I am using jQuery. I was testing the script in `Google developer console`. It is returning this error `Cannot read property 'match' of undefined .` . But it is working expected when I am entering individual command one by one.

```
q = "google.com";
var view_src = $.get('http://'+q, function(response) 
                                         { return response; 
                                         }
                           );
       var src_res = view_src.responseText;
       var reg_gg = src_res.match(/google.com/);
       console.log(reg_gg);
```

Comment: get is an asynchronous request. You have to work on the response inside the callback. Your callback return will never make it to `view_src`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `view_src`, doesn't contains `reposneText` property.

Try to move code with match to success function. Should help.